# How we can use bulk apis in elasticsearch 8.x java sdk

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bulk, java-client, elasticsearch-8

I don't see any documentation regarding bulk operations in elasticsearch 8 java sdk client.
How older bulk operation codes can be refactored with new version of elasticsearch-8 java sdk?

Comment: In the forum ElasticSearch has a similar question, look [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-the-new-elasticsearch-java-api-client-bulkoperation-bulkrequest-bulkresponse-works-similarly-with-hlrc-bulkprocessor/310356/2?u=rabbit_br).

Comment: OK.This is helpful.Atleast I am  hopeful,that bulk support is still there in sdk but since it is missing in documentation,I am not sure if it is going to be deprecated or modified heavily.